# How to get woocommerce new order billing details in log file using wordpress hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'awo_mainmenu' );

function awo_mainmenu($order_id) 
{
  error_log("$order_i`enter code here`d", 3, '/tmp/order.log' );
  die('exit');
}

enter code here
```